# Windows 8.1 upgrade download location

Tags: windows-8.1, upgrade, download, file-location

My Windows 8.1 upgrade is currently downloading via [Microsoft Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Store).

I have two laptops running Windows 8 both of which I am planning to upgrade. Since the upgrade requires downloading 3.6 GB, one such operation will take about two days with my Internet plan.

Is there a way I can use this downloaded [ISO image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) file (or make an ISO image from files downloaded) for my other laptop? Or will I have to download it again on my second laptop?

What is the directory where Windows Store places the Windows 8.1 ISO image file, or the  default download location of Windows Store? I guess it may have pre-allocated memory somewhere because none of the HDD partitions seems to be shrinking during the download.

NOTE: I have checked `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` by changing permissions and found nothing pertaining the download there. Also, appdata doesn't seem to contain any of these files.

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but at least the title is correct! This is what people search for...

Answer (score 4):

The ESD file should be stored in `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`

You should also take a look into the WindowsUpdate.log it should show the link to the file.

Comment: i found UpdateId = {3943672A-1B70-4188-A1E1-87627C3A8DCB}.1 for the download from WindowsUpdate.log and there is a file about 2.5 gb in C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a995a11f698615b8ad52250f17bc9227 but i cant access it right now
will check it when download finishes
is there any other way to track download location by UpdateId?

Comment: @Ankit - If you are looking for a magic link in order to download a single file for multiple computers isn't where Andre's comment was leading. He was just telling you where you could find the data, on a single computer, so you can trick the download into doing a checksum on data from another computer.

Answer (score 1):

After download and before continuing installation I found the install data in `C:\$Windows.~BT\`. I am willing to create an ISO file from this installation data.

But I think you can create a recovery media by following this article after upgrading: [Create a USB recovery drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive)